# Linux gpg Conflicting values set

Tags: ubuntu, gpg

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, How can I fix this problem

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/ms-teams.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, I managed to solve it by removing source list files related to ms-teams or teams:

- open directory in terminal: /etc/apt/sources.list.d
- list ms-teams related list files
- remove them

That should solve the problem.